# How to call function for object I want?

Tags: actionscript-3

I didnt know how to exactly ask the question in the title but I can explain it here. So I have this class for pawns in my game.
And in my main program i call a bunch of instances of it with different names.

```
var z1:ZeleniPijun = new ZeleniPijun();
var z2:ZeleniPijun = new ZeleniPijun();
```

Basicly I have functions for movement and other variables that I use in my code in the class.

I'm making a multiplayer game and z1 and z2 would be pawns that I move around. 
Until now I have used Switch and by knowing the ID of the player and the pawn that was clicked I moved them around the board. That means I have a switch for selecting a player and a switch inside that switch for selecting a pawn. And every time it goes trough the switch it goes to the same code but with a "different name".

For example if I roll a 4 for pawn number 1 it does

```
z1.movePawn(4);
z1.location += 4;
and other stuff that I need it to do
```

and if I roll a 3 for pawn number 2 it does

```
z2.movePawn(4);
z2.location += 4;
and other stuff that I need it to do
```

I have to copy the same code 16 times and just change the name from z1 to z2 to z3 etc...

Is there anyway I can make a function that would do that for me?

Something like this:

```
public function doStuff(pawnName:String, number:int):void{
 pawnName.movePawn(number);
 pawnName.location = number;
 and other stuff that I need it to do
}
```

and then I can just give it the parameters I want 16 times instead of copying the same code everywhere.

Comment: can't you just put your pawns in array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

send to the `doStuff` function the object that you want to do changes like

```
public function doStuff(theObj:ZeleniPijun ):void{
 theObj.movePawn(number);
 theObj.location = number;
 and other stuff that I need it to do
}
```

if you have many objects, put them in a collection, like an array an iterate on it something like

```
foreach (obj in collection){
 doStuff(obj);
}
```

this is just more or less pseudo-code, but you get the idea

Answer (score 1):

You can use the object ZeleniPijun as parameter and call the method passing the instance you want.

```
  // example creating multiples objects
  var numObjs : uint = 5;
  var objectsControl : Vector.<ZeleniPijun> = new Vector.<ZeleniPijun>(numObjs);
  var zeleninPijun : ZeleniPijun;

  for (var i : int = 0; i < numObjs; i++) 
  {
      zeleninPijun = new ZeleniPijun();
      objectsControl[i] = zeleninPijun;
  }

  // if you want to animate one object
  doStuff(objectsControl[0], 4);

  // if you want to animate them all
  for each (var zeleninPijunObj : ZeleniPijun in objectsControl) 
  {
      doStuff(zeleninPijunObj, 4);
  }

  function doStuff(pawnObj:ZeleniPijun, location:int):void
  {
      pawnObj.movePawn(location);
      pawnObj.location = location;
  }
```